# Is there a way to test if tkinter entry contain a specific word or not?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, widget, tkinter-entry

I use a tkinter for entry and search by entry boxes, is there a code i can write it to give me a message if the entry box contain a specific word (for example: bachelor)
Thanks

Comment: Umm.. What have you tried so far? Also you can use a ```StringVar()``` to get to your goal

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand how i use stringvar() for that

Comment: It's not clear what part of the problem you need help with. Do you know how to get data out of an entry widget? Do you know how to check if a sequence of characters is in a string? Do you know how to do pattern matching within a string? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Sujay was telling you to use something like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo


def check_word_in_entry(*args):
    user_input = entry.get()
    # If you don't want casing to matter, change this to:
    # if "hi" in user_input.lower():
    if "hi" in user_input:
        # print("The word \"hi\" is inside the entry.")
        showinfo(message="The word \"hi\" is inside the entry.")


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

variable = tk.StringVar(root)
variable.trace("w", check_word_in_entry)

entry = tk.Entry(root, textvar=variable)
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It calls `check_word_in_entry` each time the text inside the entry is changed. And it checks if `"hi"` is inside the entry's text.

Comment: This doesn't so much search for a _word_ as it does a sequence of characters. If you search for "hi", your code will match the word "hi" but also the word "this". It's not entirely clear if that matters to the OP.

Comment: @AhmedMohammedMohammedMorgan Can you please tell me if searching for the word `"hi"` should match things like: `"this"` because it has `hi` inside there?

Comment: @BryanOakley True.

Comment: @AhmedMohammedMohammedMorgan Just look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.messagebox.html)

Comment: Yes i want to get that please

Comment: worked fine with me, really thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
root = Tk()
def check_entry():
    v = ent.get()
    if v == "hello world":
        print("hello world")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("it is not hello world")
        print("write hello world")
        ent.delete(0,END)
ent = Entry(root)
button = Button(root,text="Click me",command=check_entry)
ent.pack()
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you , but i want if the entry contain the word as a part of text , in sqlite i use like '%' + 'the word' +'%' , can i use like that with entry?

Comment: in the if statement you can write something like if v in "hello world": it will check whether the text "hello world" is in the entry.get() result.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
ent = Entry(root)
ent.pack()
def task():
    print("hello world" in ent.get())
    root.after(1, task)  # reschedule event in 2 seconds

root.after(1, task)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You are rescheduling every 1 millisecond :D and that can take up a lot of computational power.

Comment: Thank you but sorry how can i get a messagebox as a result for that

Comment: @TheLizzard yeah it will make it one 1 millisecond so that it will work as fast as possible without any delay in the programme

Comment: @thilinaperera Yes but the user wouldn't be able to notice a 100 millisecond (0.1 sec) delay. Run the program and check your CPU usage. Then try it with a `100` millisecond delay.

Comment: @ TheLizzard True